# Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall fails when I try to set the storage

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 20.04

I want to do an Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall from a separate partition. The block structure:

```
sda
| -- sda1 vfat  /cdrom     (iso image copied) - bootable
| -- sda2 ext4 /var/crash (added by ubuntu)
```

On `sda1` I have copied the data from the Ubuntu iso and added a `nocloud` folder that contains the files `user-data` and `meta-data`.

The `grub.cfg` menu entry:

```
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall   ds='nocloud;s=file://cdrom/nocloud/'  ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
        exit 1
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
        fwsetup
}
fi
```

1. Using a simple, basic `user-data` configuration:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server2
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
```

> I get the error: "NoneType" object has no attribute "grub_device"

2. Adding `storage` layout as `lvm` or `direct` I get the same error.
3. Changing storage to:

```
storage:
    config:
    - grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
      path: /dev/sda
      ptable: gpt
      type: disk
      wipe: superblock-recursive
```

> I get the error: "No match"

4. I also tried by adding `dev/sda2` as root:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall   root=/dev/sda2 ds='nocloud;s=file://cdrom/nocloud/'  ---
```

same errors as above.

5. I tried to set the storage interactive for testing purpose:

```
interactive-sections:
    - storage
```

the autoinstall just freeze, no option to set storage available.

How can I fix this, and what are the rules to set storage in case of multiple storage devices ?

Comment: It looks like bug mentioned here.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1912674

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, either your storage medium or installation medium is corrupted. Try these things.

1. Reboot your PC (you never know, you might just have to reboot)

1.5. Make sure that ALL of your components support 20.04! If any of them do not, they will not work. This includes USB controllers, CPUs, GPUs, and Harddisks. My friend once had a very similar problem whilst trying Ubuntu. It was fixed by him trying 20.10 instead. However, he also had strange lines all over his display, since it didn't support his GPU either.

2. Re-create the installation medium (the most likely cause is a bad installation medium) (It's also important to check the hash of your ISO files after downloading them, to make sure the ISO isn't corrupted)
3. Replace your hard disk or SSD (It's not very likely, but you could have a bad drive)

Comment: the medium is ok, the cpu/gpus are also ok being virtual; I installed manually from cdrom Ubuntu on the same machine , so the components are not the problem.